# Keep selection when tabing after refresh

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have a page which automatically reloads after a certain amount of time.

The problem is I have keyboard only members who can only tab across the page, jumping from anchor to anchor, but when the page refreshes the anchor starts from the beginning again.

Is there anyway to keep the anchor highlighted where it was when refreshed?

Comment: Which control you are using to display tabs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript & Cookie for solving this.

First attach a `focus` event handler to links on the page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on("focus", function(){
        //When a link gets focus, store that information in a cookie variable
        setCookie("lastlink",$(this).text(),1);
    });
});

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Now on Page load, check if cookie has value and using JavaScript place focus back to the link

```
var lastLink = getCookie("lastlink");
    if(lastLink != "") {
    $('a').each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == lastLink) $(this).focus();
    });
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```